# Cannot find module 'npm:react@16.4.1/index.js' from 'react@16.4.1.js' hen running jest test suite with react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, enzyme

I'm trying to migrate a project from using `karma`, `phantomJs` to `jest`, but I cannot get my config files right. I keep getting the following error:

```
 FAIL  test/unit/components/SomethingWentWrong/SomethingWentWrong.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'npm:react@16.4.1/index.js' from 'react@16.4.1.js'

    > 1 | module.exports = require("npm:react@16.4.1/index.js");
        |                  ^

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (jspm_packages/npm/react@16.4.1.js:1:18)
```

Here is a snoppet with my `babel` and `jest` configuration.

```
... rest of code

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.56",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(jsx|js)?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [ "!**/node_modules/**" ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "loose": true,
          "debug": false,
          "targets": {
            "browsers": [
              "last 3 versions"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "react"
    ]
  }
... rest of code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out what the problem was, since this project is handling dependencies both with `jspm` and `npm` for some reason some packages don't get installed even after doing `npm install my_package` or `jspm install npm:my_package`. A quick look at the `node_folder` confirm that the packages were not installed even though they appeared on the `package.json`

`npm cache verified` and a new `jspm install npm: my_package` solved the issue